# Methods to introduce notifications on a webpage without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, sqldependency

We have webpage where there is notification tab. The notifications are taken from a notification table if there are any for a particular user. This event is fired when the page is refreshed.

We now want to implement something where the notification should be displayed to the user instantly without refreshing the page.

I know about SIGNALR with sql dependency. But with sql dependency there comes database polling overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can have SignalR notify clients of database changes without polling the database.

Have a look at [this tutorial about SignalR database notifications.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M)\

It works the following way: Exactly after you update the database, you call the method to update clients along with the data.

Hope this helps. Best of luck!